# load multiple javascript file with using one javascript file

Tags: javascript

i want to load multiple javascript file using one javascript file

i have four javascript

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ec2-174-129-44-226.compute-1.amazonaws.com/apiTools/jquery.livequery.js"></script>        
<script src="http://localhost/effbugs/apiTools/tools.js?apikey=fztxljpnxqtssgtiquwr&pid=1"></script>
```

i want to intergrate above four javascript in one javascript file that i will load one instead of four and i will work proper

please give me suggestion for that

please help me

thanks...

Comment: What back-end framework are you using? Rails has an Asset Pipeline that does exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) along with [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) ?

Answer (score 4):

Well, there are a few options:

**1. Combine them into one file**

Here is how you can do it with [cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29):

```
cat jsfile1.js jsfile2.js jsfile3.js ... > combined.js
```

**2. Load them via require.js**

More info at [requirejs.org](http://requirejs.org/).

**3. Create an script element for each URL and append it to DOM**

```
/**
 * loader.js
 */

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        urls = ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js",
            "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js",
            "http://ec2-174-129-44-226.compute-1.amazonaws.com/apiTools/jquery.livequery.js",
            "http://localhost/effbugs/apiTools/tools.js?apikey=fztxljpnxqtssgtiquwr&pid=1"];

    urls.forEach(function (url) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = url;
        head.appendChild(script);
    });
});
```

Comment: I think OP is looking for something most like "Combine them files into one file."

Comment: Ok, fair enough what I don't get though is that you use `getElementsByTagName('head');` for cross browser support yet you use `Array.forEach`? Just wondering...

Comment: @Connor I could use `document.head` instead. BTW I didn't have cross-browser support in mind. It's just valid ES5.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way to include all js files, But while loading I guess they loads asynchronously and they might not maintain order the order.

```
var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
scriptElement.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js';
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple, you just copy the content of all 4 files and place them into 1 file in order like this.

**Master.js:**

```
// Content of jquery-1.10.1.min.js
// Content of jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js
// Content of jquery.livequery.js
// Content of tools.js
```

Or

**Master.js:**

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'jquery-1.10.1.min.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);

// Do this for each file
```